# How to Update json object value in array from another array of same json object structure in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm working on angular project using Typescript and I have the following array1:

```
 array1: any = [
        {
         'garantie': 'A',
         'checked': false
        },
        {
         'garantie': 'B',
         'checked': false
        },
        {
         'garantie': 'C',
         'checked': false
        },
        {
         'garantie': 'D',
         'checked': false
        },
        {
         'garantie': 'E',
         'checked': false
        },
        {
         'garantie': 'F',
         'checked': false
        }
    ];
```

and i have another array that contains same json object structure , this is the code :

```
array2: any = [
    {
     'garantie': 'A',
     'checked': true
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'D',
     'checked': true
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'F',
     'checked': true
    }
];
```

my issue is I want to update the checked property of the second array based on guarantee property, this the result that I want:

```
[
    {
     'garantie': 'A',
     'checked': true
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'B',
     'checked': false
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'C',
     'checked': false
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'D',
     'checked': true
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'E',
     'checked': false
    },
    {
     'garantie': 'F',
     'checked': true
    }
];
```

i try this code but dosen't work :

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (this.array1[i] !== undefined && this.array2[i] !== undefined) {
        if (this.array1[i].garantie === this.array2[i].garantie) {
          this.array1[i].checked = this.array2[i].checked;
      }
      }
    }
```

please do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your current loop is comparing both arrays at the same index - which, while it works for `A`, will not work for the second index and so on. You should be attempting a `find` in the second array to find the matching element from the first array. If a match is found, then update. Also, dont hardcode that loop counter, use `array1.length`

Comment: @tymeJV thanks for your response , do you know please the syntax on how to find match element in typeScipt?

Comment: `let matchingObj = array2.find(a => a.garantie === array1[i].garantie); if (matchingObj) { do stuff }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple map operation and a nested find operation.

```js
array1 = array1.map(i => {
  return {
    garantie: i.garantie,
    checked: (array2.find(k => k.garantie == i.garantie) || i).checked
  }
});
```

`array.map` takes an input array and transforms each element based on some condition. 
`array.find` finds a matching element in an array based on some condition.

For each element in array1, you keep garantie, and update checked if the matching element is found in array2, otherwise you keep the current checked.

Here's the above in action on your input jsons.

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    'garantie': 'A',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'B',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'C',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'D',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'E',
    'checked': false
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'F',
    'checked': false
  }
];

var array2 = [
  {
    'garantie': 'A',
    'checked': true
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'D',
    'checked': true
  },
  {
    'garantie': 'F',
    'checked': true
  }
];

array1 = array1.map(i => {
  return {
    garantie: i.garantie,
    checked: (array2.find(k => k.garantie == i.garantie) || i).checked
  }
});

console.log(array1);
```